# The value of EOF different for different specifiers?

Tags: c, formatting

> Im using Codeblocks.

Below is the program in C:

```
/*to find the value of EOF ( End Of the File ) Number */

#include<stdio.h>
int main()
{

    printf("The EOF value is: %d %5ld",EOF, EOF);
    /*when EOF specified in %d specifier it is giving the value as -1, but if its 
         given %ld then a number  4294967295 is printed on the console?*/
    return 0;
}
```

As i said in the comments of the program:

- *when EOF specified in %d specifier it is giving the value as -1, but if its 
           given %ld then a number  4294967295 is printed on the console?*

I'm using 64 bit Linux OS on HP. [ if it matters to compiler about assigning the memory for ints, floats and longs ]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's probably defined as `(-1)`, so it's implicitly an `int`. So it is correctly shown as -1 when printed using `%d`. However, passing an `int` to `printf()` when a `long` is expected invokes undefined behavior.

What *probably* happens, is that your system uses 2's complement, a 32-bit `int` and a 64-bit `long` and the bit pattern for `(int)-1` is the same as what corresponds to `(long)4294967295`.